# Spring 3.0.5 Junit testing issue

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, junit

I wanted to do spring junit testing to be implemented in my project, I am facing an issue. 
1.I wanted a scenario where i can use one spring version jars for junit(src/test) and another spring version of jars for the running main java class(src/main) is it possible. I mean when spring is in testing phase it should use the spring 3.2.4.release  and while building the ear it should use 3.0.5.release jars. is it possible.
2.since the project is in 3.0.5.release  and we wanted to use @WebAppConfiguration for testing which is not allowed in spring 3.0.5.release  is there any way to do this (@WebAppConfiguration) in spring 3.0.5.release

Comment: Why can't you move to 3.2.4.release version for all?

Comment: It will requires to check the campatibility of all the project dependencies, which will take more time

Comment: 3.2.4 is backwords compatiable with 3.0.5.

Comment: but i am getting so much issue with 3.2.4 jars

Comment: Can you be more specific, What kind of issues...

Comment: Since my project is little complicated where spring jar are used by another jars., and there are few conflict are there. but i dont know about it now. i have to check. my humble request is, whether there will any issue will exist..??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77124/discussion-between-ramesh027-and-igreen).